# Finding the rate at which the water level is rising

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, volume

Water is being poured into an inverted right conical vessel whose apex angle at $90°$ at a constant rate of $3\,\text{cm}^3/\text{s}$. At what rate is the water level rising when the depth is $π\,\text{cm}$.

Hi,I can easily solve these kind of problems, but this time there is no radius or height given that i can use to solve this problem. Can anyone help me with this.
Thanks.

Comment: The problem states "when the depth is $\pi$ cm", which means that the height of the cone of water in the vessel is given to you.

Comment: Have you drawn a labelled  picture in order to determine the information that you need?

Answer (score 1):

Since the apex angle is given as $\;90^{\circ}$, the base angles are each $45^{\circ},\;$ thus $\dfrac{r}{h} = 1$

$h\;$ has already been given as $\pi$

You now have all the information you need.

Proceed...